# Какой есть быстрый способ чтения файла и записи в файл?

Tags: python, python-3.x, оптимизация, csv

У меня есть файл data.txt с данными:

```
111,Pablo1,Alar1,mail1,0,0
222,Pablo2,Alar2,mail2,0,0
333,Pablo3,Alar3,mail3,0,0
444,Pablo4,Alar4,mail4,0,0
555,Pablo5,Alar5,mail5,0,0
```

Сейчас я его считываю сначала в лист из строк, потом в листе эти строки преобразую также в листы и получается так:

```
list_of_lists = [
['111','Pablo1','Alar1','mail1','0','0']
['222','Pablo2','Alar2','mail2','0','0']
['333','Pablo3','Alar3','mail3','0','0']
['444','Pablo4','Alar4','mail4','0','0']
['555','Pablo5','Alar5','mail5','0','0']
]
```

Потом я изменяю какой-нибудь элемент:

```
new_list = list_of_lists
new_list[0][1] = '100000'

# new_list = [
# ['111','100000','Alar1','mail1','0','0']
# ['222','Pablo2','Alar2','mail2','0','0']
# ['333','Pablo3','Alar3','mail3','0','0']
# ['444','Pablo4','Alar4','mail4','0','0']
# ['555','Pablo5','Alar5','mail5','0','0']
# ]
```

После чего я листы в new_list преобразую в строки с пробелами и все перезаписываю в data.txt. Это очень много времени занимает с большими объемами данных.

Как можно это ускорить?

Знаю, что есть csv, но разве он сильно быстрее?

Comment: Используйте базу данных sqlite, чтобы не читать вручную файлы

Comment: «много» это сколько? «большими» это какими? Нагрузка на процессор или на диск? Может, вам надо просто SSD купить?

Comment: Непонятны эти вот "потом", все нужные преобразования можно делать "на лету" прямо в процессе чтения/записи данных. Но в любом случае делать такие вещи через `Pandas` гораздо удобнее.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Откройте для себя модуль [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/10min.html)!

```
import pandas as pd  #  pip install pandas

df = pd.read_csv("/path/to/file.csv", sep=",", dtype=str)
df.iloc[0, 1] = "100000"
df.to_csv("/path/to/result.csv", index=False)
```

Аргумент `dtype=str` - используется исключительно для ускорения парсинга CSV - этот параметр укажет `pd.read_csv()` не пытаться определить правильный тип данных для каждого столбца, а воспринимать все столбцы как строки.

PS советую сравнить скорость обработки данных вашим текущим способом и вариантом из этого ответа ;)

---

Если у вас нет жесткой привязки к формату хранения данных, то имеет смысл хранить данные либо в бинарных файлах (например Parquet, HDF5, Pickle, etc.) или же в реляционной БД (MariaDB, PostgreSQL, SQLite, etc.) - это может еще сильнее ускорить работу с данными. Кроме того при работе с БД - вы бонусом получаете вариант когда вы можете параллельно писать в таблицу разными потоками / процессами. Параллельное чтение данных поддерживают все известные мне реляционные БД.

**NOTE:** **параллельная запись не поддерживается в `SQLite`**, т.к. пишущий процесс эксклюзивно блокирует файл БД.

[Здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37012035/5741205) можно посмотреть слегка устаревший результат сравнения чтения / записи табличных данных для различных форматов файлов.